# Non-curly quotes in code?

Tags: symbols, pdftex, verbatim, code

Here is a quick question, how to use tex to print this `'` symbol? An example is shown below:

```
data 'a list = Nil | Cons (e, 'a list)
```

I tried to use `'` or `, but they all looks bad.. I am sorry but I am not a native English speaker, so I don't even know the name of `'`..

Could anyone help me on this simple problem? thank you

Comment: If it's Lisp code (I assume), have you tried the [listings](http://ctan.org/pkg/listings) package with `basicstyle=\ttfamily` to make it look like a typewriter font?

Comment: One obvious choice is $\prime$, but your best bet is to check the comprehensive list of latex symbols.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the package `upquote` and put the code in a `verbatim` environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{upquote}
\begin{document}
\begin{verbatim}
data 'a list = Nil | Cons (e, 'a list)
\end{verbatim}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect, this is what I am looking for!