# tikz - How to input ' symbol

Tags: tikz-pgf

How can I input ' symbol in tikz node?

I wish it looks like

[image]

But actually '9' will be like below in tikz:

```
\node[draw] (N) {'9'};
```

[image]

Comment: this is not a TikZ issue ... you need to use adequate font, which provide desired shapes.

Comment: @Zarko Oh, how should I select right font?

Comment: @Zarko is correct: my answer below works without tikz, also.

Comment: here on site are many question how to identified some font. If you have pdf reader document with this '9', than look for used fonts. As you can see,  fonts used in this comments is very similar to what you looking for. unfortunately I don't know, which one is used here. I'm not font experts :-(

Comment: here are two previous questions that deal with "straight quotes": [Straight quotes?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/52529) and [Non-curly quotes in code?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/238298)

Comment: @barbarabeeton: feel free to mark it as a duplicate if you feel so inclined.

Answer (score 5):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{textcomp}     


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw] (N) {\textquotesingle9\textquotesingle};    
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: you can improve solution with `\node[draw,font=\sffamily] (N) {\textquotesingle 9 \textquotesingle};`. this gives better approximation of showed example

Comment: Good suggestion, thanks.  OP appears happy with the solution as provided, though.  I think s/he was mostly looking for straight quotes instead of curly ones.