# Single quotes deformed in code section

Tags: verbatim, sourcecode

The following `verbatim` section:

```
\begin{verbatim}
$ curl -i -G  -X POST \ 
       'http://localhost:8888/deploy' \
       --data-urlencode 'name=z' \
       --data-urlencode 'code=function f(event, callback){callback(null, 3)}'
{"newFile":"functions/z.js"}%
\end{verbatim}
```

Is displayed as:

[image]

Note that the quotes around `'http://localhost:8888/deploy'` and all other single-quoted texts are converted to `’http://localhost:8888/deploy’`, which of course breaks the code when it is copy-pasted to a terminal, editor or IDE.

Is there a way to tell verbatim to use the *exact* characters of the source, without prettifying any characters?

Comment: what you ask is the default behaviour so something in the code you have not shown is changing that. Please fix the example so it is a complete document that reproduces the issue so people can debug.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/238298/24974

Comment: by default  in the cmtt font the `'` character is not straight but it is a `'` and should cut and paste as such.