# How to display "´" character in a lstlisting environment

Tags: listings

I am using the package listings and I am trying to get the following output :

ExportDirective=    ´export´,ID,[´(´,(IdDomain|IdFunction|IdRule),{´,´,(IdDomain|IdFunction|IdRule)},´)´|´*´];

from :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[breaklines=true]
ExportDirective=´export´,ID,[´(´,(IdDomain|IdFunction|IdRule),{´,´,(IdDomain|IdFunction|IdRule)},´)´|´*´];
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

but the apostrophes doesn't show up on the pdf. How can I fix it?

Comment: And if those do not show up search for `literate` on this site or in the manual (this is the option which can help you).

Comment: potential duplicate: [Non-curly quotes in code?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/238298) (or possibly [Straight quotes?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/52529))

Answer (score 2):

Use `literate`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[breaklines=true,literate={´}{{\'{}}}1]
ExportDirective=´export´,ID,[´(´,(IdDomain|IdFunction|IdRule),{´,´,(IdDomain|IdFunction|IdRule)},´)´|´*´];
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Much nicer output (in my opinion) can be achieved by adding

```
\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily,columns=fullflexible}
```

to the preamble.

[image]